How do I tell programs to show colors by default in eshell?
M-x eshell is working pretty well for me with windows, but I'm fighting colors.
eshell supports colors very nicely these days, but most programs don't recognize that by default.
I could, for example, run git config [--global] color.ui always and also run export MYPY_FORCE_COLOR=1 and a bunch of other settings, but there has to be some reason why all these programs are treating eshell exactly the same way, and it would be nice if I knew why that was so I could treat the cause all at once.
What I've tried
Most of what I find when I've searched relates to getting eshell to support colors at all, but of course it does that by default now. I did try
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook (lambda () (setenv "TERM" "xterm-256color")))

but it did not seem to affect anything.
In conclusion

What is causing these programs to treat eshell as an environment that doesn't or shouldn't support color?
Is there any way I can change my environment or my ~/.emacs.d/init.el that will change that behavior across these programs?


You may need https://github.com/atomontage/xterm-color/

Can you provide a step-by-step recipe (preferably starting from emacs -Q) that when followed will show me what the problem is? I have reread your question a few times but I still don't understand what the problem is. E.g. if I start with emacs -Q and start eshell with M-x eshell, here's a screenshot of a session after I typed in a few commands. Can you explain your question in similar terms perhaps?

@NickD That's Interesting. Yes, I agree with your screencap; it looks like ls honors the $TERM env var. I don't know why e. g. git or mypy don't.

I have no problems with git: after git config set config.ui true, I get colors with git branch, git status, git log, git diff. See the screenshot. I don't have mypy so I cannot say anything about that. I presume that you can use some option (like --color for ls) or some configuration (like git config) to make it show colors. If you can reproduce my results for ls and git, but still cannot make mypy do the same thing, you should edit your question to clarify and limit it to that case.

The main point is however, that each program has to be told in its own way to produce the relevant ANSI escape codes that need to be added inline when sent to  a terminal that can interpret them to produce colors. Emacs cannot do anything about that: each program may have its own mechanism (an option like --color or a configuration setting like git config set color.ui true). I believe the usual way is to define aliases (see e.g. /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh  for the bash case on a Fedora system - YMMV).

Right I made clear in the original post that I already know I can find settings for each individual program, but there's some reason why e. g. the git default of color.ui auto behaves correctly in MinGW and PowerShell but not eshell. You could argue that's a problem with git and not eshell, but then you have to believe it's just a crazy coincidence that other programs like mypy behave exactly like git in that way, and I think it's easier to believe that there is something about the eshell environment which is causing e. g. git config color.ui auto to behave unexpectedly.
